# .JS.ERB can't recognize variables

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pusher

I am new to .js.erb files, and I am using them because I need to construct a Javascript string that needs Ruby variables.

Here is my code.

pusher.js.erb

```
var pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER KEY);
var myChannel = pusher.subscribe('job_channel');
$(document).ready(function() {
    myChannel.bind('job_added', function(data) {
        addJob(data)
    });

    function addJob(data) {
        <% job = JSON.parse(data) %>
        var new_job = "HELLO <%= job.id %>";
        $('.job_list').append(new_job)
    };

});
```

`data` holds a Ruby object called `job` that I converted to JSON. I want to turn that JSON object back into a Ruby object and use its attributes to construct a Javascript string. I know I can simply just use `data["id"]` in this example, but this is just sample code and I need a lot more complicated Ruby stuff to go into that string.

When I try to start the server and load a page, I am getting this error:

> undefined local variable or method `data' for #<#:0x007ffe07cb7e58>
>         (in /PATH/javascripts/pusher.js.erb)

```
app/assets/javascripts/pusher.js.erb:17:in `block in singletonclass'
app/assets/javascripts/pusher.js.erb:65530:in `instance_eval'
app/assets/javascripts/pusher.js.erb:65530:in `singletonclass'
app/assets/javascripts/pusher.js.erb:65528:in `__tilt_70364478302900'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1231815935649534974_70364476328360'
```

Answer (score 1):

ERB passes through text and performs operations or writes out text based on ruby code it sees inside certain escape sequences. You have two escape sequences that ERB will process:

```
<% job = JSON.parse(data) %>
var new_job = "HELLO <%= job.id %>";
```

data is not being defined in ERB / ruby scope, which is why you are seeing the above error. It appears you may be getting the ERB / ruby code mixed up with the javascript code. They operate independently of one another.

Comment: does this mean that naming your file something.js.erb doesn't necessarily allow you to access controller variables in your js file?

Comment: No, I was just trying to say that you have to think about the ERB pass and the resulting javascript independently. ERB is manipulating text in ruby land while the resulting javascript will work with whatever text the ERB manipulations have resulted in. I think the error in the question was a result of thinking that the data variable was defined in ruby / ERB land, when it wasn't.